# how to run storm topology in my machine ...im having storm in my machine

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

storm jar storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0-beta1.jar storm-starter-master.jar production-topology local

**I'm getting the error:**

> Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -client
>   -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1 -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/clojure-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/ns-tracker-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/clj-time-0.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.7.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/tools.namespace-0.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/java.classpath-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/cheshire-5.3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-1.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/tigris-0.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/ring-json-0.3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/ring-devel-1.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/ring-servlet-1.3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0-beta1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/conf:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/bin
>   -Dstorm.jar=storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0-beta1.jar storm-starter-master.jar production-topology local Error: Could not
>   find or load main class storm-starter-master.jar

Answer (score 0):

The problem arise because the storm jar is run at incorrect directory. check where your jar is present and run it from there.